# "pushes" matching UIInterpolatingMotionEffect? (i.e. access "physics" on UIInterpolatingMotionEffect)

Tags: ios, accelerometer, physics, gyroscope, uimotion

With UIInterpolatingMotionEffect, twist the iPhone, and you can have an image move.

Now: imagine a red block you will "bounce around" on screen, using UICollisionBehavior and UIDynamicItemBehavior. When the user twists the iPhone: I want the boxes to "start moving" WITH SIMILAR PHYSICS FEEL to using UIInterpolatingMotionEffect.

http://tinypic.com/player.php?v=b67mlc%3E&s=8#.VBVEq0uZNFx

Aside:UX explanation: the bouncy effect (example: SMS on iPhone) has the same "feel" as the parallax image effect in iOS.  (By "feel" I really just mean the same speed, acceleration.)  This would be a third effect: like parallax it would "move things slightly" but they would "keep moving", bouncing a little.  (You could say, somewhat combining the feel of bouncy-lists-effect and and parallax-images-effect.)

Now: it's relatively easy to do what I describe, using CMAccelerometerData, and applying pushes using UIPushBehaviorModeInstantaneous. But it's a lot of messy code.

In contrast, UIInterpolatingMotionEffect is **ridiculously easy** to use.

Essentially, how can I get the values from UIInterpolatingMotionEffect (which I will then use as pushes). Cheers!

---

## Similar thought ...

[Simply display the values of UIInterpolatingMotionEffect?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25810558)

It asks simply: how can one easily "just get" the values from UIInterpolatingMotionEffect ?  ie, it seems incredible one has to go to the effort of carefully subclassing CALayer, etc.

Comment: Yes, I don't know of any UIKit Dynamics behavior that links to the accelerometer, so you might still have to go through the `CMMotionManager` process. As an aside, I'm not sure I would employ a push, associated with the accelerometer information, but rather would either would adjust the `UIGravityBehavior` or `UIAttachmentBehavior` on the basis of the `CMMotionManager` information. It depends upon the desired UX. I guess you could do an push when the device tilt goes across some threshold, too, but it's not a UX I'd gravitate towards (no pun intended).

Comment: You might advice on how to simplify the code, you might want to add the salient portions of the code to your question. That also might make the desired UX a little more clear as I'm having a hard time reconciling "similar to `UIInterpolatingMotionEffect`" with `UIPushBehavior` (like I said, it feels more like a "changing attachment" than a "push").

Comment: R ... (1) thanks a million on the Gravity/Attachment suggest, i will thoroughly try-out that approach.  (2) Note that indeed, the linked question is perhaps a better expression of the question at hand.  (I easily "know what to do" once I get those values; it seems incredible it's so hard to get those values!)  (3) Re the "UX value" - I added a few words & video in the question.  For sure, one could see the sms-pushy-effect in iOS, and the parallax-bg effect in iOS, as, completely useless and silly (many consumers do feel that). Certainly "it's just an effect.")

Comment: Re point 3, I wasn't trying to make any pejorative statement about the value of these sorts of effects, but rather was merely saying that I was unclear what precisely the desired effect was in this particular case. Lol.

Comment: lol no for sure - I added a vid !!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's an interesting notion of updating some behavior via the `UIInterpolatingMotionEffect`, though I don't suspect it's designed for that. If you want to update behaviors based upon accelerometer information, I personally would have thought that the `CMMotionManager` is ideal for that purpose.

The desired UX isn't entirely clear from the video clip, but it looks like that video is having things continue to slide in the direction the phone is tilted until you stop tilting the phone. If that's what you want, I'd be inclined to marry `CMMotionManager` with a UIKit Dynamics `UIGravityBehavior`:

```
self.animator = [[UIDynamicAnimator alloc] initWithReferenceView:container];

UICollisionBehavior *collision = [[UICollisionBehavior alloc] initWithItems:container.subviews];
collision.translatesReferenceBoundsIntoBoundary = YES;
[self.animator addBehavior:collision];

UIGravityBehavior *gravity = [[UIGravityBehavior alloc] initWithItems:container.subviews];
gravity.gravityDirection = CGVectorMake(0, 0);
[self.animator addBehavior:gravity];

self.motionManager = [[CMMotionManager alloc] init];

typeof(self) __weak weakSelf = self;

[self.motionManager startDeviceMotionUpdatesToQueue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] withHandler:^(CMDeviceMotion *motion, NSError *error) {
    if (weakSelf.referenceAttitude == nil) {
        weakSelf.referenceAttitude = motion.attitude;
    } else {
        CMAttitude *attitude = motion.attitude;
        [attitude multiplyByInverseOfAttitude:weakSelf.referenceAttitude];
        gravity.gravityDirection = CGVectorMake(attitude.roll * 5.0, attitude.pitch * 5.0);
    }
}];
```

If you want them to move precisely in accordance to the attitude, stopping the movement when you stop moving the device (like `UIInterpolatingMotionEffect` does), you could use a `UIAttachmentBehavior`, something like:

```
UIAttachmentBehavior *attachment = [[UIAttachmentBehavior alloc] initWithItem:viewToAttachTo attachedToAnchor:viewToAttachTo.center];
[self.animator addBehavior:attachment];

self.motionManager = [[CMMotionManager alloc] init];
self.motionManager.deviceMotionUpdateInterval = 1.0 / 20.0;

typeof(self) __weak weakSelf = self;

CGPoint originalAnchorPoint = viewToAttachTo.center;

[self.motionManager startDeviceMotionUpdatesToQueue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] withHandler:^(CMDeviceMotion *motion, NSError *error) {
    if (weakSelf.referenceAttitude == nil) {
        weakSelf.referenceAttitude = motion.attitude;
    } else {
        CMAttitude *attitude = motion.attitude;
        [attitude multiplyByInverseOfAttitude:weakSelf.referenceAttitude];
        attachment.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(originalAnchorPoint.x + attitude.roll * 10.0, originalAnchorPoint.y + attitude.pitch * 10.0);
    }
}];
```

Note, in both of those examples, I'm applying the adjustments to the behaviors as the device shifts from the orientation of the device when the user started the app. Thus I capture a `CMAttitude` property, `referenceAttitude` to be the attitude of the device when the user fired up the app, and then uses `multiplyByInverseOfAttitude` on subsequent updates to apply gravity in relation to that original orientation. You could, obviously, use a predetermined attitude if you wanted, too.

But hopefully the above illustrates one approach to tackling this sort of UX.

Comment: incredible example code thanks man! I'll try those out and compare.  As a curiosity I'll put in the code we refined too currently, it looks great on any "box of blocks".

Comment: Wonderful answer, one note to keep in mind - "Because the processed events might arrive at a high rate, using the main operation queue is not recommended."

Comment: Agreed. You can either use `deviceMotionUpdateInterval` (like in my second example) or use background queue (but if you do the latter, don't then just turn around and dispatch updates back to the main queue; you have to use dispatch source or other mechanism to decouple the UI updates from the motion events).